# SQL, Link to Element Feature

Tags: sql, enterprise-architect

I have two classes. One Attribut of class1 is connected to another attribut of class2.  This was done with the help of the context menue of the connector in the proximity of one class, it is called **Link to element feature**. The same is done on the other side of the connector to select the other attribut of the other class.  So the connector directly connects two attributes and not the classes itselves.  I haven´t found the tables, where this infomation is stored, so I dont find the appropiate SQL to find connected (or not connected) attributes.

Comment: **[EDIT]** your question and add the definition of the tables (as `create table` statements) some sample data and the expected output based on that data. [_Formatted_](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code) **text** please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)  And tell us which DBMS you are using

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the way for notes using `Link to..`

- PDATA1 = 'Attribute'
- PDATA2 = t_attribute.ID of the attribute
- PDATA3 = name of the attribute
- PDATA4 has 'Yes' (I don't recall what that's used for so you can probably ignore it

First SQL:

```
SELECT PDATA2 FROM t_object WHERE Object_Type='Note' AND PDATA1 = 'Attribute'
```

will give you the ID. Just put that in another SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM t_attribute WHERE ID = (above SQL)
```

and you have the attribute details. Or if you want to find the unmapped one just build a dissection with the found IDs from the first with the existing attribute IDs.

For associations using `Link to...` it's a bit more tricky. First off, any such connectors have the relevant information stored in `t_connector.StyleEx` like e.g.

```
LFEP={69A30E17-23AB-4641-9573-9BDBAA988D52}L;
```

> `LF<dir>P=<guid><pos>;` connector is attached to attribute/operation
>   `<dir>` = S or E meaning Start (source) or End (target) `<guid>` = ea_guid of `t_attribute` or `t_operation`
>
> `<pos>` is the edge (L or R) where the connector had been attached to in the moment when the link has been created. This is a superfluous information since the renderer will attach the link to whatever place is relevant.
>
> There can be one LFSP, one LFEP or both be present in one StyleEx property

(from my Inside book)

Now you can filter that information with a SQL or (what I prefer) with a little script, since doing complex SQL string operations are not my expertise.

Comment: Thank you very much, it works perfectly to find attributes which has a linked note, so it fits to the edited question. Actually i need something different. I have two classes. One Attribut of class1 is connected to another attribut of class2. This was done with the help of the context menue of the connector in the proximity of one class, it is called "Link to element feature". The same on the other side of the connector to select the other attribut. So the connector directly connects two attributes and not the classes itselves. I haven´t found the tables, where this infomation is stored.

Comment: I have added the way to go for the 'other' `Link to..`